# Woocommerce Cart Total Price Support

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I need your support on a matter; I just can't seem to figure it out. The issue is as follows: When I add the following to the page, it works:

```
<div id="paytr_taksit_tablosu"></div>
```

`< script src="https://www.paytr.com/odeme/taksit-tablosu/v2?token=0000000000000000000000000000111111111&mer chant_id=01234567&amount=**Product-Price**&taksit=0&tumu=0"></script----->`

When I enter a value in the **Product-Price** where the product price is specified, the installment table is displayed automatically. However, I want it to automatically take the value in the Product Price section from the total of the cart, and I haven't been able to achieve this. Could you please help me if there is a chance? Thank you.

I am waiting for your support.